# Invalid table name error, when execute alter stored procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle

```
-- Disable constaint, good
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE cpl_disable_constraint(table_name IN varchar2, constraint_name IN varchar2)
AS

BEGIN
   execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE :1 DISABLE CONSTRAINT :2' using table_name, constraint_name;
END;
/


-- Bug
declare
  table_name varchar2(100) := 'ADV_TEST_COURSE_CREDIT';
  column_name varchar2(100) := 'SEQUENCE_NUMBER';
begin
  cpl_disable_constraint(table_name, column_name);
end;
/
```

I'm getting these errors:

> ORA-00903: invalid table name
>
> ORA-06512: at "SISD_OWNER.CPL_DISABLE_CONSTRAINT", line 5
>
> ORA-06512: at line 5
>
> 903. 00000 -  "invalid table name"

Any idea?

Comment: You can't pass an identifier (=table name) as a parameter.

Comment: Is the table in your current schema or not?

Answer (score 0):

As a_horse_with_no_name mentioned, you can't pass an identifier to `execute immediate` as a parameter. You have to put it in the SQL statement.

```
execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE ' || table_name || ' DISABLE CONSTRAINT :1' using constraint_name;
```

Note that this will open you up to SQL Injection if you don't carefully validate the table_name variable. I usually do something like this before calling `execute immediate`, to make sure the table_name variable is the valid and correct table name for the constraint, and not some malicious string like `null; DROP TABLE ADV_TEST_COURSE_CREDIT;`:

```
select c.table_name into table_name from user_constraints c where c.constraint_name = constraint_name;
```

(By the way, this is part of why people often choose a prefix for local PL/SQL variable names, like "v_table_name", to keep them separate from column names. You can see it's a little confusing in the query above.)

Also I'd like to point out that in your function definition, you're calling the second parameter "constraint_name", but in the anonymous block you're calling it "column_name".